# Database crashed, need help recovering

Tags: mysql, crash, innodb

I try to restart, and get this error:

> ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
>   Starting MySQL. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/www.mysitecom.pid).

Look at the log.. see a ton of this :

```
140502 14:10:24 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140502 14:10:24 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140502 14:10:24 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140502 14:10:24 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140502 14:10:24 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140502 14:10:24 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140502 14:10:24 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
140502 14:10:24  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Error: trying to add tablespace 12 of name './roundcube/searches.ibd'
InnoDB: to the tablespace memory cache, but tablespace
InnoDB: 12 of name './d6nspw4f_dell/wp_users.ibd' already exists in the tablespace
InnoDB: memory cache!
```

Was able to restart by adding `innodb_force_recovery = 4` to the sql config file, but all sites that touch the db are now broken and can’t be written to.

When I try to do a mysql dump of all tables, I get the error :

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1146: Table 'x3hmcpl_hmcpl.blocked_ips' doesn't exist when using LOCK TABLES
```

Any help at all would be appreciated. We don't have a database guy here and I'm stuck with the task of trying to fix it as quickly as possible.

Comment: check this thread http://linuxadministrator.pro/blog/?p=225 it might help you.

Answer (score 2):

`innodb_force_recovery = 4` puts InnoDB in read-only mode, it's not supposed to repair corrupted InnoDB tablespace.

Take a dump of all databases (mysqldump -A > mydb.sql) and recreate MySQL datadir.